# How to pass json latlng to googlemap (onMapReady Method)?

Tags: android, android-maps-v2, android-maps

I want to pass json value to onMapReady method. But when i am passing the value to onMapReady i am getting null value.

```
protected void status(){
        try {


            JSONArray peoples = new JSONArray(myJSON);
            JSONObject c = peoples.getJSONObject(0);
            lati = c.getDouble("latitude");
            loni = c.getDouble("longitude");
            }catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        googleMaap = googleMap;
//I want to get value of lati && loni here here
    }
```

Comment: Can you clarify the question, For me it looks Hard at the same time Easy.

Comment: Why not just move the whole try-catch block directly in `onMapReady`? Although there are many ways to achieve your desire.